# Back Button Acting like a Refreshing key

Tags: android, eclipse, button, video, back

When I click on the back button while testing my app it refreshes the same activity instead of going back to the previous one.  Also the video start then it stops and tells me "Cant Play This Video" 
Here are the first and second activities codes:

```
import android.app.Activity;
public class Help extends Activity {

CheckBox c[] = new CheckBox[21];
private Button btn;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.help);

    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
    c[0]= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.bulk);
    c[1]= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cond);


import android.app.Activity;
public class Med extends Activity {
VideoView vid;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.med);
    vid = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.setups); 
    String urlpath = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.setups;
    vid.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(urlpath));
    vid.start()
```

Comment: post your code please

Comment: Please kindly post your code!

Comment: it could happen if you are launching two intents to the same activity. Going back will make the app to show the same activity since it is duplicated in the stack